# Logging for Kubernetes Calico NetworkPolicy?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I am new to Kubernetes `NetworkPolicy` and the Network plugin `calico`.

I have successfully implemented `calico` in my Kubernetes cluster:

```
[root@node1 ~]# kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o wide | grep calico
kube-system     calico-kube-controllers-5d8b5bc986-sllmk                          1/1       Running
kube-system     calico-node-4wk8f                                                 1/1       Running
kube-system     calico-node-5kz99                                                 1/1       Running
kube-system     calico-node-bfk9w                                                 1/1       Running
kube-system     calico-node-f2tb2                                                 1/1       Running
kube-system     calico-node-hrcf4                                                 1/1       Running
kube-system     calico-node-wvh8d                                                 1/1       Running
```

I have also configured relevant network policies and they work perfectly fine.

The only only I am concerned about is logging. I am unable to find any logs that could tell me whether some request is being accepted or blocked.

Ive tried checking the logs of the `calico-nodes-*` pods but they do not provide any reasonable logs.

Are there any others logs that I can look at ?

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect calico-node containers logs across your Kubernetes cluster within this path `/var/log/calico`, or it can be modified via `--log-dir` parameter used in `calicoctl node run` command, as described in this [link](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v1.5/usage/troubleshooting/logging).

However, if you want to observe logs along [CNI Network](https://chrislovecnm.com/kubernetes/cni/choosing-a-cni-provider/), please visit this [page](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/troubleshooting).

I found it very helpful to log out events from Calico CNI using `kubelet` as target point and then collect them via `systemd`, besides you can specify a value for `log_level` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes `NetworkPolicy` doesn't support logging, but Calico's native `NetworkPolicy` supports a "log" action that allows you to log packets to the system log.

Tigera's (***disclaimer:*** I work for Tigera) commercial product, CNX, which is built on Calico offers additional auditing and compliance features so you might want to check that out.